# Archimedean totally ordered groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it true or not $\mathbb Z + \alpha\mathbb Z$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z + \beta\mathbb Z$ as an ordered (totally ordered) subgroup of the real numbers? where $\alpha, \beta$  are different non-zero rational numbers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By the extended Euclidean algorithm, if $n/d$ is written in lowest terms, we can find

$$ u\frac{n}{d} + v = \frac{1}{d}$$

and so

$$\mathbb{Z} + \frac{n}{d} \mathbb{Z} = \frac{1}{d} \mathbb{Z}$$

and multiplication by $d$ gives an isomorphism of ordered groups

$$ \frac{1}{d} \mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{Z} $$

Comment: The above calculation is related to the topic of "invertible ideals" which you may or may not find interesting.

Comment: Thanks Hurkyl for nice argument. Still, I am not clear for ordered abelian group.